# RxJava marge arrays with different sizes

Tags: java, rx-java

Let's say I have 3 arrays with different lengths.

```
String[] array1 = new String{"1", "2", "3", "4"};
String[] array2 = new String{"1", "b", "c"};
String[] array3 = new String{"@", "#"};
```

I want to merge them to get the following result:

```
{"1", "a", "@", "2", "b", "#", "3", "c", "4"}
```

Does it possible to do this with RxJava? if not what other solutions will you advice? 
P.S. arrays cant be in any kind of different lengths.

Comment: A simple algorithm should do the trick. I don't see anything in this task that would benefit from RxJava's features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to do this with RxJava, here is how I'd do it:

```
public class RoundRobinCollector {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Observable<Object> o1 = Observable.just("1", "2", "3", "4");
        Observable<Object> o2 = Observable.just("a", "b", "c");
        Observable<Object> o3 = Observable.just("@", "#");

        Object tag = new Object();
        Observable<Object> otag = Observable.just(tag);

        Observable<Object> p1 = o1.concatWith(otag.repeat());
        Observable<Object> p2 = o2.concatWith(otag.repeat());
        Observable<Object> p3 = o3.concatWith(otag.repeat());

        Observable.zip(p1, p2, p3, (a, b, c) -> {
            List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
            if (a != tag) {
                list.add(a);
            }
            if (b != tag) {
                list.add(b);
            }
            if (c != tag) {
                list.add(c);
            }
            return list;
        })
        .takeWhile(list -> !list.isEmpty())
        .concatMapIterable(v -> v)
        .toList()
        .subscribe(System.out::println)
        ;
    }
}
```

Given the original source observables, I pad them at the end to become "infinite" thus there appear to be "equal in length". I zip them and in the function, I prepare a list from those columns which don't have the padding. If the end list is empty, the `takeWhile` will complete the sequence. Then I flatten the sequence with `concatMapIterable`, collect it into a list and print the result.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering. It seems it is more complex to do that with Rx than to have a simple algorithm to do that. I just thought there might be a function out of the box in Rx for such a issue. But as my original question was related to RxJava way to solve this issue I accept this answer as the right one.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by **akarnokd** is the correct answer if you want to solve this issue with RxJava, but I end up with a simple algorithm like **laune** suggested, cause with RxJava it becomes more complex that it is. I just thought that RxJava can have some sort of function out of the box which could do that for me. So here is what I did in the end:

```
private List<Item> mergeItems(Response response){
        ArrayList<Item> mergedList = new ArrayList<>();

        final int eSize = response.getEvents().size();
        final int cSize = response.getCommunities().size();
        final int vSize = response.getVenues().size();

        final int maxSize = Math.max(eSize, Math.max(cSize, vSize));

        for (int i = 0; i < maxSize; i++){

            if(i < eSize){
                mergedList.add(response.getEvents().get(i));
            }

            if(i < cSize){
                mergedList.add(response.getCommunities().get(i));
            }

            if(i < vSize){
                mergedList.add(response.getVenues().get(i));
            }
        }

        return mergedList;
    }
```